# Alternatives to completion handlers in Swift with Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I’m trying to implement a 3-tiered architecture for my iOS app and I am trying to get it to work with Firestore calls.

So in this app, my controller calls my service, which in turn calls the repository, which then makes calls to Firebase directly. An example of the code is shown below:

```
import Firebase

let db = Firestore.firestore()

func repositoryLoad (completion: @escaping ((DocumentSnapshot?, Error?)) -> Void) {
     db.collection("users").document().getDocument { (document, error) in
        completion((document, error))
    }
}

func serviceLoad (completion: @escaping ((DocumentSnapshot?, Error?)) -> Void) {
    repositoryLoad { (document, error) in
        completion((document, error))
    }
}

func controllerLoad (completion: @escaping ((DocumentSnapshot?, Error?)) -> Void) {
    serviceLoad { (document, error) in
        completion((document, error))
    }
}
```

As you can see, calling information from firebase through the layers makes the syntax rather troublesome, and therefore highlights my need for a more "elegant" solution.

Thus, my question is that if I call Firestore at the repository level, does it mean that I have to implement completion handlers in the functions for services and controllers? If so, are there any alternatives to this, any libraries I can use? If not, what should I be doing instead?

As an aside, I was researching functionality like the async/await(which I understand to be treating the results of asynchronous calls to be already evaluated) in C#/JS and I found things like DispatchGroup and DispatchSemaphore, which unfortunately did not work for me. Since then, I’ve found that these concepts deal with multi-threading, and not exactly with the issue of handling asynchronous results(which is what I want) like in completion handlers. But, please do correct me if I’m wrong about anything!

I’m rather confused with working with asynchronous code, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by implementing a completion handler?

Comment: Basically do stuff with the information pulled from firestore!

Comment: Would you mind to post some code so that it is easy to understand your question?

Comment: Data from Firestore indeed is available in callback/closures/completion handlers only. If you're having trouble making that work, edit your question to include the minimal code that shows what you're trying to do and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

RxSwift is a framework of Reactive programming in swift. It might be best solution for handling asynchronous calls.